# Submit form data to database

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have one general article model that I want to add comments to

```
Schema::create('article_comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->BigIncrements('id');
   $table->unsignedBigInteger('article_id');
   $table->foreign('article_id')
      ->references('id')->on('articles')->onDelete('cascade');
   $table->string('name', 128);
   $table->string('email', 128);
   $table->text('text');
   $table->timestamps();
```

I created a form, substituted values ​​there

```
<?php

use \App\Models\Article;
    
/**
* @var ArticleBlock $article
*/
?>

<form method="post" action="{{ route('send-comment') }}">
    <div class="row">
        <input type="hidden" name="article_id" value="{{ $article->id }}" />
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-item">
                <label for="name">Your Name *</label>
                <div class="input-wrapper">
                    <img src="/img/user.svg" alt="user logo">
                    <input id="name" type="text" name="name">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-item">
                <label for="email">Your Email *</label>
                <div class="input-wrapper">
                    <img src="/img/mail.svg" alt="mail logo">
                    <input id="email" type="email" name="email">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-item">
                <label for="text">Comment *</label>
                <div class="input-wrapper">
                    <img src="/img/comment-alt.svg" alt="comment-alt logo">
                    <textarea id="text" name="text"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input class="submit-button" type="submit" value="Submit Comment">
</form>
```

Route

```
Route::post('send-comment', 'App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController@sendComment')->name('send-comment');
```

Function in the controller

```
public function sendComment(Request $request)
    {
        $articleComment = new ArticleComment;

        $articleComment->name = $request->get('name');
        $articleComment->email = $request->get('email');
        $articleComment->text = $request->get('text');
        $artile = Article::find($request->get('article_id'));
        $article->article_comments()->save($articleComment);

        return back();
    }
```

But in the end, after filling out the form, the data does not come and the comment is not created. And when I click on the submit button, I get this

> 419 | PAGE EXPIRED

What could be the problem? If you need more information, I'm ready to provide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the [CSRF token](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/csrf#preventing-csrf-requests) in your form which is causing the error.

You should add the CSRF token in your form and send it with the post request.

Add [@csrf](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/csrf#preventing-csrf-requests) within the `<form>` tag as:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('send-comment') }}">
@csrf
...
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, there was still a problem in this, but now I still have no article ID, and because of this error, what could be the problem?

Comment: I added to the post how I'm trying to get the `$article` on the article page

Comment: @meow, ``$artile = Article::find($request->get('article_id'));`` it should be ``$article = Article::find($request->get('article_id'));`` You have a typo in the article word.

Comment: now comments are being added, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Missing @csrf on your form as below

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('send-comment') }}">
    @csrf
    <div class="row">
        <input type="hidden" name="article_id" value="{{ $article->id }}" />
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-item">
                <label for="name">Your Name *</label>
                <div class="input-wrapper">
                    <img src="/img/user.svg" alt="user logo">
                    <input id="name" type="text" name="name">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-item">
                <label for="email">Your Email *</label>
                <div class="input-wrapper">
                    <img src="/img/mail.svg" alt="mail logo">
                    <input id="email" type="email" name="email">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-item">
                <label for="text">Comment *</label>
                <div class="input-wrapper">
                    <img src="/img/comment-alt.svg" alt="comment-alt logo">
                    <textarea id="text" name="text"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input class="submit-button" type="submit" value="Submit Comment">
</form>
```

plus final line on your migration codes you miss the $table and you've written just table

```
Schema::create('article_comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->BigIncrements('id');
   $table->unsignedBigInteger('article_id');
   $table->foreign('article_id')
      ->references('id')->on('articles')->onDelete('cascade');
   $table->string('name', 128);
   $table->string('email', 128);
   $table->text('text');
   table->timestamps();
```

Comment: thanks) in migration just a typo in copying